# jQuery when pointed to a link should show a div that's hidden by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hashchange

I have a page where there are a few divs hidden by default. I would like to be able to point users to a link where it would show the divs.

ex. https://app.emailsmsmarketing.com/login

Users are able to click "Register" which hides the login div and shows the register div. What I'm trying to accomplish is basically adding a link to the main site from where users will be able to access the registration form by default (using jQuery only).

ex. https://app.emailsmsmarketing.com/login#!register (or something like that)

Basically what I'm asking is:

a) is is possible to do this
b) if so, how?

I'm not sure if this makes sense to anyone. I appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably looking for this: [Anchor-based URL navigation with jQuery](http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/2007/12/04/anchor-based-url-navigation-with-jquery)

```
var myUrl = document.location.toString();
if (myUrl.match('#')) { // the URL contains an anchor

  var myAnchor = '#' + myUrl.split('#')[1];
  $('#login').hide();
  $('#register').show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can examine the `document.location` property during `ready` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (document.location.indexOf('#login') > -1)
    $("#login").show();
});
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me but the answer by Samich did.

Answer (score 0):

Well sure, just set a class or id or something on your link, like so:

```
<a href="#" class="register"> Register! </a>
```

Then do this in jQuery

```
$("a.register").click(function() { 
    $("#logindiv").hide()
    $("#registerdiv").show();
    return false; // prevents the default behavior of the link, ie following it
});
```

Where registerdiv is the ID of your hidden div etc.

Comment: I mean from another page. I already have what you suggested implemented.

Comment: Just so I'm sure that I understand - You want to load content from the server, and show it on the current page? Please clarify.

Comment: No. I already have a page with the code you provided. I want to link from http://www.emailsmsmarketing.com to https://app.emailsmsmarketing.com/login but I want it to show the register div instead of the default login div. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Ooh, now I get you. I think VMAtm answered it quite nicely then.