# Direct link to the content

Tags: javascript

I have a page http://bartle96.narod2.ru/demo.html there are 4 links to the hidden content

Is it possible to make a direct link to the content such as "dolphin".

So that when you click on a link http://bartle96.narod2.ru/demo.html#delfin immediately opened a photo with a dolphin

Comment: There are many questions that already cover this type of thing. Please search SO.

Comment: Also, what part of this involves AJAX?

Comment: You'd have JavaScript on the page that looks at the url, parses the anchor tag, and then shows/hides elements as needed

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery when pointed to a link should show a div that's hidden by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329585/jquery-when-pointed-to-a-link-should-show-a-div-thats-hidden-by-default)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define and open needed content on `onload` event.

Check this post where you can find the same behaviour:

[jQuery when pointed to a link should show a div that's hidden by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329585/jquery-when-pointed-to-a-link-should-show-a-div-thats-hidden-by-default/7329637)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hash value using `window.location.hash`. Then set the pic you want based on the value.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var pic = window.location.hash;
  if ( pic === "#delfin" ) {
    // Show picture of dolphin
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just a comment on the OP's technique, but it's also better to hide the DIV's on display instead of through a `STYLE` attribute. This way, if the JS doesn't work, the content is still viewable.

Comment: Also, I doubt the `if` statement is needed, I think the OP just meant that as an example. (Of course, that's actually not that clear, but this would be a poor technique in practice when it could just call `article(hashbang)`)